# Problem when trying to create a table on SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to create a table on SQL Developer, and I had the error called "Missing left parenthesis", which I think it can be almost anything.

The code is this, and the 3 tables take the same error:

```
CREATE TABLE cliente (dni VARCHAR2(10), CONSTRAINT dni_pk PRIMARY KEY,
                     nombre_cli VARCHAR2 (50), CONSTRAINT nombre_cli_nn NOT NULL,
                     apellidos VARCHAR2 (50),
                     direccion VARCHAR2 (50),
                     f_nac DATE);

CREATE TABLE producto (cod_prod NUMBER (10), CONSTRAINT cod_prod_pk PRIMARY KEY,
                       nom_prod VARCHAR2 (50), CONSTRAINT nom_prod_nn NOT NULL,
                       precio VARCHAR2 (50));

CREATE TABLE compra (dni_cli NUMBER (10),
                      cod_prod NUMBER (10), CONSTRAINT cod_prod_pk PRIMARY KEY, 
                      cantidad NUMBER (10),
                       CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_prod_fg FOREIGN KEY(cod_prod) REFERENCES producto(cod_prod),
                       CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_cli_fg FOREIGN KEY(cod_cli) REFERENCES cliente(dni_cli));
```

I have tried a lot of things and none has worked. It is probably something silly, so I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: No `,` should be before `constraint` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The issues were that the primary key constraint expects you to specify the columnname. I.e. `PRIMARY KEY (column_name). You also used the wrong column names in the Foreign Key constraint declaration. Lastly, there was a difference in column types between the key columns in the 2 initial tables and the referencing table, and you reused the same name for the cod_prod_pk constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE cliente (
                     dni VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
                     nombre_cli VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
                     apellidos VARCHAR2(50),
                     direccion VARCHAR2(50),
                     f_nac DATE,
                     CONSTRAINT dni_pk PRIMARY KEY (dni)
);

CREATE TABLE producto (cod_prod NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
                       nom_prod VARCHAR2 (50), 
                       precio VARCHAR2 (50)
                       , CONSTRAINT cod_prod_pk PRIMARY KEY (cod_prod));

CREATE TABLE compra ( dni_cli VARCHAR2(50),
                      cod_prod NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
                      cantidad NUMBER (10),
                       CONSTRAINT cod_prod_pk2 PRIMARY KEY(cod_prod), 
                       CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_prod_fg FOREIGN KEY (cod_prod) REFERENCES producto(cod_prod),
                       CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_cli_fg FOREIGN KEY  (dni_cli) REFERENCES cliente(dni));
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=138b464f3a5319d528345a001546bd45)

Comment: Thanks you! It works, so I definitely forget named the constraint.

Comment: About the others 2 tables, I try the same reasoning, but doesn't work...

Comment: @ManuelLucas - Check the updated answer. I tried describing the issues I encountered in the fiddle.

Comment: Okey, everything it ok! Thank you so much for the help. I'm a begginner on Database, so I have some trouble with easy thing.

Comment: @ManuelLucas You're most welcome. If the answer helped you, please consider marking it as such. This will ensure that future visitors might find the proper resolution faster. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whe you are declaring in-line constraints you should not have a comma between the data-type and the constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cliente (
  dni VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT dni_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre_cli VARCHAR2 (50) CONSTRAINT nombre_cli_nn NOT NULL,
  apellidos VARCHAR2 (50),
  direccion VARCHAR2 (50),
  f_nac DATE
);

CREATE TABLE producto (
  cod_prod NUMBER (10) CONSTRAINT cod_prod_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  nom_prod VARCHAR2 (50) CONSTRAINT nom_prod_nn NOT NULL,
  precio VARCHAR2 (50)
);
```

You also have an issue that some of the columns you are referencing from/to do not exist:

```sql
CREATE TABLE compra (
  dni_cli NUMBER (10),
  cod_prod NUMBER (10) CONSTRAINT cod_prod_pk PRIMARY KEY, 
  cantidad NUMBER (10),
  CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_prod_fg FOREIGN KEY(cod_prod) REFERENCES producto(cod_prod),
  CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_cli_fg FOREIGN KEY(cod_cli) REFERENCES cliente(dni_cli)
);
```

gives:

```
ORA-00904: "COD_CLI": invalid identifier
```

and the constraint should probably be:

```sql
CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_cli_fg FOREIGN KEY(dni_cli) REFERENCES cliente(dni)
```

but then you get the error:

```
ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type
```

As the types do not match. You need to resolve this.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e7390d26970ae3907c6fb348279df8f5)